# d3js won't draw circles using data array

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an d3js SVG drawing that I am doing as follows:

d is an array that contains of entries like

```
  var d=[{"x":370,"y":40,"label":"Label 1"},    
        {"x":370,"y":150,"label":"Label 2"} ];
```

and code for d3 is like this

```
    // here el is my HTML element and width/height are sizes
    var svg=d3.select(el).append('svg')
    svg.attr({width: width, height: height});

    // this works just fine
            svg.append("circle") // attach a circle
                .attr("cx", 200) // position the x-center
                .attr("cy", 100) // position the y-center
                .attr("r", 50);
    //  now trying to plot that 'd' array

            svg.data(d)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cy", function (d) {                    
                    return d.y
                })
                .attr("cx", function (d) {

                    return d.x
                })
                .attr("r", 10);
```

the latter instruction won't produce the svg elements. No errors displayed, too. Functions inside "cy"/"cx" are called ok. Please let me understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My d3 is a little rusty unfortunately, but you appear to have missed a `selectAll`. Try the following instead:

```
svg.selectAll("*").data(d)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cy", function (d) {                    
        return d.y
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x
    })
    .attr("r", 10);
```

Take a look at the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pet9e/) to see this in action; from what I can tell, the `selectAll` is used to filter out any values that may already exist. Even with `"*"` as a CSS selector, no values match so all the items from `d` are used.

Comment: As an aside (so not part of the answer directly) http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ appears to give a good background in the usage of `selectAll`.

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question: if I am drawing some second set, I can not use selectAll("*") as it messes with previous drawing. What I should do?

Comment: Can't say with 100% certainty, but try `.selectAll(".first")` and `.selectAll(".second")`, as a (bad) example. If that doesn't work, ask it as a new question.